# jsf - register SessionListener in faces-config

Tags: java, jsf, listener, faces-config

I created a `SessionListener` but it doesn't work because I don't know how to register it in the `faces-config.xml`. I tried the following:

**SessionListener**

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {


    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String param = request.getParameter("language");


    IDAdminLanguage idl = (IDAdminLanguage) JSFUtils.resolve("#{languageBean}");

    if (param != null && param.length() > 0) {
        idl.setLanguage(param);
    } else {
        idl.setLanguage("de");
    }   
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) { }
```

}

**faces-config**

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>ch.idadmin.util.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: You've a major bug in your code. The `FacesContext` is not necessarily available during creating of the session. Do not use `FacesContext` in a `HttpSessionListener`. Or, just do not use a `HttpSessionListener` but the (post)constructor of the `IDAdminLanguage`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yuu need to add that configuration in `web.xml` (and not in faces-config.xml)

```
<web-app ...>
        <listener>
        <listener-class>ch.idadmin.util.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```